# Is it good to use LOOKUP For One-To-Many Relationship?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

in Access : 
If I'm Connecting two Tables as One-To-Many Relationship , Is it good To add Lookup Field at one of those tables . instead of the normal relationship ?

Example : 
Well , The Relationship is `EMPLOYEES M ------WORKS FOR------ 1 DEPARTMENT`

- Department ( Department_ID **(AutoNumber)** , Department_Name .. etc )
- Employees ( Employee_ID **(AutoNumber)** , Employee_Fnmae , Employee_Lname , ... Department_ID **(LOOKUP)** )

Comment: I haven't worked in MS Access in quite a few years, but if memory serves, lookup's primary effect is on the UI. Unless lookup also creates a foreign key, you'll need to create the foreign key yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using Sharepoint, I would not suggest look-ups. The MVPs MS Access site lists a number of reason why you should not: http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a 'lookup' just map the relationships.
You may create a third table which just maps the relationship called

```
EmployeesDepartment ( autonumber, EmployeesID, DepartmentID )
```

This gived you the flexibility to add additional tracking on this relationship as well. (historical departments by adding dates)